# Django Server Side set-up for pagination with Datatable

Tags: django, datatable, pagination

I am using Django for backend, and I am using Datatable library to display a large number of records ( approx 1 million records ). I am trying to set up datatable in such a way that
every time 25 records are being fetched from the backend and when the user clicks on the next page button, another ajax call gets the next 25 records and so on.

But I am having a trouble setting these up.

My DataTable initialisation :

```
$("#company-table").DataTable({
      "processing": true,
      "serverSide": true,
      "bDestroy": true,
      ajax: {
        type: "POST",
        url: "/get_results/",
        headers: {
          "X-CSRFToken": getCookie("csrftoken"),
        },
        data: {
          ...other data params...
          page:$("#company-table").DataTable().page()
        },
      },
      columns: [
        ...populating columns...
      ],
    });
```

And my views.py looks like this ( It is completely wrong as far as I know ) :

```
    #filtered_queryset contains all the records.

    paginator = Paginator(filtered_queryset, 25) # Show 25 contacts per page.
    page_number = request.POST.get('page')
    start = request.POST.get('start')
    length = request.POST.get('length')
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)
    data = list(page_obj.object_list.values())
    return_data = {"data": data}      
    json_data = json.dumps(return_data,indent=4, sort_keys=True, default=str)
    return HttpResponse (json_data, content_type = "application/json")
```

Can anyone help me? Or just nudge me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one [django-ajax-datatable](https://github.com/morlandi/django-ajax-datatable)
I hope this will work

Comment: Please try not to provide link-only answers. Please try to ensure the answer is self-contained, so that if the link becomes unavailable, your answer will still be useful. This does not mean you should copy/paste the entire contents of the link into the answer - instead you should provide a clear and concise summary, to answer the specific question. (You should still show us where you got the information you are presenting in the answer.)